# Java RMI for implementing server side of system

Tags: java, architecture, client-server, rmi

I am developing system, that consists of client (written in JavaFX) and server. Now I am going to implement server. Users will download clients. Clients will communicate with server (only one server and many clients). Server will communicate with data base and send results. Server will support authentication and different requests (not http of course). Is it a good idea to implement server with Java RMI? If no, could you advice me any good idea about server realisation.

Thanks a lot for future questions!

Comment: i'd suggest to go with Httpclient otherwise if you have strong reason to use RMI

Answer (score 0):

RMI is bit kind of traditional but still powerful to me ,it has some draw back . But, despite the RMI there is also a chance for you to use java sockets class ? just like a client -server application ...